# Tag Synonym: [bit-twiddling] and [bit-manipulation]?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, synonym-request

Of these two tags, [bit-twiddling](/questions/tagged/bit-twiddling) **x44** seems to be simply a less-formal version of [bit-manipulation](/questions/tagged/bit-manipulation) **x1,287**

They both seem to cover similar topics, with similar techniques. I can't see any reason these should remain as seperate tags.

Comment: Am now thinking about twiddling bits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [has been suggested already](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bit-manipulation/synonyms). [bit-twiddling](/questions/tagged/bit-twiddling) is a proposed synonym of [bit-manipulation](/questions/tagged/bit-manipulation), and currently has a score of 3. If one more person votes for that synonym, it will be approved and take effect.

Of course, I can't cast that last vote because I don't have the required score of 5 on the [bit-manipulation](/questions/tagged/bit-manipulation) tag. You'll have to find someone who is an expert on bit manipulation…

Comment: Well, now I feel silly.

Comment: No reason to feel silly. Our tag synonym suggestion feature is what's silly. First because it's well-hidden. Second because it doesn't let trusted users participate, the ones that know best how the tag system works.

Comment: @CodyGray: Totally agree. I hate this system. It just does work. For years. And it doesn't look like it's a subject to be changed soon.